# Effects in plm are meaningless?

Tags: r, regression, panel-data, plm

In R, the plm function documentation of package plm, we can read about possibility of choose one of three effects `individual`, `time`, `twoways`. Why such exists if I can just pick model type which already specifies which effect to use ? E.g. 'within' model will only use `individual` and `random` will always pick `twoways`. To say more - for example `pooling` model by definition takes no effect (no `time` and no `individual`) so choosing effect in this case is meaningless. What's the purpose of this additional input?

Comment: The statistical content of this questions relates to the effects being meaningless in case of the `pooling` model, which is correct and, thus, the software disregards this input in the pooling case. However, it does not disregard the `effect` input in the other cases and does not perform as depicted in the question ("within will only use `individual` and random always uses `twoways`" - neither of both statements is true).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How do you come to this conclusion? The within model can be used with "individual", "time" or "twoways". You should see different results for your model coefficients, when choosing a different effect. Also, for example, when you use "time" or "twoways", you should be able to get the specific time effects via

`summary(fixef(yourmodel,type = "level", effect="time"))`.

(My plm package version is 2.2-4.)

Comment: Nice, didn't realize so far that `fixef` has a `summary` method! +1